# Cannot post from clipboard in chat or right click

Tags: support, chat

This has happened to me before. I cannot right click or paste content into the chat input.

Right now, it's affecting me in the [ECMAScript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59354/ecmascript) chatroom, but not the [JavaScript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) chat room.

I am using latest Chrome and Mac OSX if that helps. I don't use many extensions, so I doubt the ones I do use would effect it.  Does anybody know why this occasionally happens to me? It's quite annoying since I can't paste any blog articles or even code I'd like to share / get help on.

Update: this bug went away, but is back today. It has spread. I can no longer for the time being copy and paste from anything on the Stack network. Every other site and application on my computer does not have this issue. It is no longer chat specific for me.

Comment: Has your clipboard been invited into the ECMAScript chatroom?

Comment: Had same issue earlier today....directly related to my unsuported browser constantly trying to enter compatability mode though.

Comment: @Retsam the guy with the clipboard said my clipboard owed him money, so I guess it wasn't allowed in :(

Comment: Can reproduce this is definitely a bug and it happens. Goes away when I restart chrome.